# LeaveRequest cannot handle exception when input the day belongs to blocked day

Tags: php, laravel-5

[Leave request form example - part of a module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uSZS.png)

I have a problem in this part only. I dont know how to handle in the input.

I have table `Events` (event_type_id, from_date, to_date). I have inserted a new `event_type_id` which is `2` - Blocked day from day 13 to 15.

I have a table `LeaveRequest` (leave_from_date, leave_to_date). But I create a leave request from 13 to 15.

I have created successfully but not handle the exception that if the Event blocked day from 13 to 15 but I input in `LeaveRequest` is from 13 to 15, it must send error.

I use Laravel framework and in my LeaveRequest for handle input, i just handle the leave_status only

```
public function rules()
    {
        return $rules = [
            'leave_status' => 'required|integer|between:0,3',
          ]; 
    }
```

Is there anyway to handle error like this. Thank you. I have done for 5 days but no solution.

Comment: What do you mean handle, what is your final goal? If you replace Request with LeaveRequest on your controller method, it will use those rules.

Comment: i mean how can i check the days i want to create a leave request it is not belongs to type 2. I have said an input up in my status

Comment: "I have table Events (event_type_id, from_date, to_date). I have inserted a new event_type_id which is 2 - Blocked day from day 13 to 15.

I have a table LeaveRequest (leave_from_date, leave_to_date). But I create a leave request from 13 to 15."

Like i said up there.